# AngularJS: How to use $index inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have such ul:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="menu">
    <li ng-repeat="availableAlphaName in availableAlphaNames" data-original-index="0" data-optgroup="1" class="">
        <a tabindex="0" class="opt  " style="" data-tokens="null">
            <span class="text">{{availableAlphaName.Name}}</span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span>
        </a>
    </li></ul>
```

**data-original-index** must have index value. But if I set **data-original-index** to $index it will be always 0 because every instance gets its own scope.

Please, help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Your question is not related to your problem.
Please, describe it or write a more specific question.

Comment: How do you try to read the data-original-index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify `track by $index` within the `ng-repeat`

```
    <li ng-repeat="availableAlphaName in availableAlphaNames track by $index" data-original-index={{$index}} data-optgroup="1" class="">
        <a tabindex="0" class="opt" style="" data-tokens="null">
            <span class="text">{{availableAlphaName.Name}}</span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
```